# _producer.on ready event is not emit when i restart kafka server

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I need to check the kafka status dynamically so I tried

```
this._producer.on('ready', function () {
  console.log('kafka is ready!');
});

this._producer.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('err: kafka is not ready');
});
```

but when i restart the kafka ready event is not triggered.
Kindly advice.

NOTE: I am trying to create a custom circuit breaker for all services so that i need to check frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a broker dies, a new leader will be elected if one is available.

The producer will only periodically update its metadata to fetch the next leader, it will not be immediately notified, at least not until the next batch gets sent.

If you want to find cluster health (still via cluster requests, not dynamically), I'd recommend using [AdminClient](https://kafka.js.org/docs/admin#describe-cluster), not a producer.

To do it dynamically, you should install some TCP service monitor directly on the brokers, e.g. Nagios, Prometheus Blackbox exporter with a TCP check, DataDog Agent, etc. then you can hook those into service monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution what I expect,

```
client.on("close", () => {
  console.log("kafka close");
});

client.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("kafka connect");
});

client.on("reconnect", () => {
  console.log("kafka re-connect");
});
```